# Cannot install virtualbox extension pack

Tags: virtualbox

```
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.24.vbox-extpack
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You don't install the extension pack with dpkg. You install it **inside** of Virtualbox.

Answer (score 3):

it's a package bug, fix to be released shortly: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-ext-pack/+bug/1605799

just wait a few days, update and try again.

Comment: It is not sure if this BUG is related to the post. Maybe the version of virtual box the user has installed is the current one namely 5.1.12.  this version belongs to the date when the SO creates the post.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem
I went to:
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.24/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.24.vbox-extpack
I selected open with VirtualBox
When the download finished VB ask to install, I accepted the license and it installed correctly.
Copy the link and paste in your browser and you'll get this:

[image: Download extension pack]

When finish download VirtualBox opens with a dialog to install it and then you click install and you get the license agreement:
Accept it and it will finish the installation

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.24/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.24.vbox-extpack

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit kernel and which  version of virtualbox you have already installed. Plesae add those information to your question.

Comment: @Hölderlin this is not a question.

Comment: @Anwar I know but it would be interesting for all who will try the answer. It is necessary to check if the requirements matches those in the response, because the question also not resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

You must use the version of extension pack from the official site. Just check your vbox version before downloading.

But wrong package blocking dpkg, so that was a problem.

To solve that just remove this package using

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq virtualbox-ext-pack
```

and then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: YMMV, but the above dpkg got Drupal 7 going for me on Ubuntu 16.04.