# Error while installing virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg

error :

```
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using ubuntu 16.10. I am trying to install virtual box but it is not getting installed.
it shows

```
 sudo apt-get install virtualbox
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox is already the newest version (5.1.6-dfsg-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer     required:
  libudev1:i386 linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.6-2) ...
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading:        http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Exten    sion_Pack-5.1.6.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.6.vbox-extpack
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit      status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried

```
sudo sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

but its not working

Comment: The problem you have belongs to the `Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.6.vbox-extpack`. Please see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/857824/cannot-install-virtualbox-extension-pack/857832#857832) and what I mentioned under point 3. It belongs to the key you have to register via `wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`,, which is all described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, it worked. May you explain the above commands?

Comment: Sure, 
apt-get purge virtualbox*  -- > this command will purge all virtualbox package and left over file of virtualbox.
sudo apt-get update  --> it will downloads the package lists from the repositories and updates them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies to be install