# virtualbox-ext-pack E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: virtualbox

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of dpkg is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-47
  linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-45
  linux-tools-4.4.0-45-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-47
  linux-tools-4.4.0-47-generic ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.0.18-1) ...
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.18/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.18.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.18.vbox-extpack
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what you have and what you have done: Which Ubuntu version, and how you installed VirtualBox.

Comment: Does this Q&A help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/857824/cannot-install-virtualbox-extension-pack?

Answer (score 1):

may be you have to first uninstall or remove the post-installation script ofvirtualbox-ext-pack which conflict with this new one and after that u try to install it.

try may be your problem solve:

sudo apt-get purge virtualbox

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install virtualbox